# CABasicAnimation change duration/speed during rotation

Tags: rotation, cabasicanimation

I am using CABasicAnimation to rotate forever an imageView and I want to change rotation speed during rotation. Can anybody help me with this?
    Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

You can see https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/AdvancedAnimationTricks/AdvancedAnimationTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH8-SW2

And I use this code.

Objective-C

```
self.layer.timeOffset = [self.layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil]; 
self.layer.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime(); 
self.layer.speed= theSpeedYouWant;
```

Swift

```
self.layer.timeOffset = self.layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), fromLayer: nil)
self.layer.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime();
self.layer.speed = speed;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can start a new basic animation with different speed and take as the start value the one you receive from the presentation layer.

Comment: How to do that? Could you write an example